# Is it possible to create a vertical column chart with FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I want to know that is it possible to create a vertical column chart in FPDF as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

Infact i want to display a sigle vertical bar divided into sub parts to represent different percentage for different categories.

Is it possible with FPDF and if it is possible give me some tips how to draw it in a pdf file created with FPDF.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion as an image

```
// Insert a chart in the top-left corner at 300 dpi
$pdf->Image('my-vertical-column-chart.php',10,10,-300);
// Insert a chart as dynamic image from a URL
$pdf->Image('http://www.myhost.com/mysite/my-vertical-column-chart.php?chartparam=value',60,30,90,0,'PNG');
```

File `my-vertical-column-chart.php` might be any type of bar chart image generator, like:

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/oimg?key=0AlYEM-11PerqdDltWXllSGJ4QzVra2ZTeGdTeXFHWEE&oid=3&zx=3y0dpvwbqv97
  [image]

I did it in Google Drive and shared as image. It is the fastest way to do the job;

- http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/docs/
- http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/?gclid=COanmpfQ7bECFQReTAod8yUA-w
- http://phpchart.net/
- http://pchart.sourceforge.net/
- https://developers.google.com/chart/
- etc., even your personal php GD data representation, if you have enough graphic design talent ;)

Comment: Have you created this chart with FPDF or with another library? Can is see the code you have used for generating this chart

Comment: I created this chart in Google Documents. FPDF can create graphical primitives, but not objects like chart, graph, gantt of diagram. The link to the source - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlYEM-11PerqdDltWXllSGJ4QzVra2ZTeGdTeXFHWEE

Comment: May be you want to draw chart STRICTLY by the FPDF objects? In case you need some class/function/method, which combine 8 calls of text output for labels, 4 filled rectangles and 6 lines, then I have to answer: "No, I have not it, sorry!"

Comment: No problem no need to be sorry and thanks a lot for the effort you have made